# Uncaught, unspecified "error" event

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm encountering this error "Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (Incorrect arguments)" when trying to login using postman. Please help me figure out the incorrect arguments.

Here is my code:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({
    username: req.body.username
  })
  .select('password')
  .exec(function(err, user) {

    console.log('err', err); // err is null

    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.status(404).send({message: 'User does not exist!'})
    }
    else if (user) {
      var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);

      if (!validPassword) {
        res.status(401).send({message: 'Invalid Password'});
      }
      else {
        var token = createToken(user);
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Successfully login!',
          token: token
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

})

the exact error:

`events.js:165
      throw err;
      ^
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (Incorrect arguments)
    at Function.emit (events.js:163:17)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (..../node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2322:23)
    at runCallback (timers.js:574:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:554:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:533:5)`

I'm using:

- Node 6.6.0
- Mongoose 4.7.5
- MongoDB 2.4.9

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you have provided. Are you sure the error is bubbling from somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Found what cause the error, it's from my other code and it's because I'm using arrow function instead of anonymous function.

```
// don't use arrow function if you want to access the this keyword
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = (password) => {
  var user = this;

  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
}

// use anonymous function instead
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password) {
  var user = this;

  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
}
```